# How to Constraints Objects to Curve Path?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, constraints

[image]

Hello, I am somewhat new to blender. I am working on a short animation and want to have a sun/moon objects rotate through the sky. I thought it would be easy to somehow constrain the objects to a circle curve and then all I would need to do is animate the curve.

Is there a way to do this? I cant figure it out. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem is that you're using a mesh as the path.

What you want to use is the bezier circle under the *Curves* menu when you press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd>

Once that's done,

- Click your moons and then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> click your curve
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and choose *Follow Path*.

That should do what you want

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).